# Windows 10 boot and repair fail after trying Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS on a USB stick

Tags: boot, live-usb, windows-10

Newbie wannabe user of Ubuntu here. Excuses for the total ignorance displayed beforehand. I created a USB stick with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS and wanted to try it out to see if I would like it to replace Windows 7 on my old living room laptop which I mainly use for media and some gaming purposes.

This morning I plugged it into my desktop which runs Windows 10 to have a look around and (foolishly, I realize now) opened the software updater app in the Ubuntu try out version. It downloaded something, don't know what and once again foolishly I thought it would update the Ubuntu software on the stick. Well, I was wrong. It asked me to reboot the desktop PC and now I can not boot in to my Windows 10 OS any more.

I have run memory checks, tried the windows repair function which comes up over and over and for some reason does not recognize recovery points that are on the main SSD drive. Also managed to get into the HP setup utility, (not sure if this is the BIOS to be honest, but think it is) and ran checks (DPS self test) there, which were ok and changed the boot order to eliminate boot from USB. I think that the download changed something in the startup file of Windows 10 but am not sure. Through the command window option I tried looking at the logfile which came up in one of the notification windows. E:\Windows\system32\logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt but because it's a Spanish install somehow the keyboard reverted to its default keyboard and I couldn't find the backslash symbol. Facepalm..

Now here I am, managed to get into the Ubuntu stick again and now writing from the FF browser in the Ubuntu trial version to ask if there is anybody who can help me further. I have tried the Ubuntu file explorer to see if I could get in to the "windows" folder on the SSD but it rejects me. How ever I am able to see the system file and pretty much everything else in "other locations" but honestly am "very" reluctant to mess around in boot folders etc.

My "experience" to solve this ends here. Is there anybody who can point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Ubuntu flash drive installer is not update-able. It is just like a DVD and is considered a hybrid DVD/flash drive. You can create versions with persistence which allows you to save some data. Not sure what you then did. Windows 7 systems typically are BIOS on MBR(msdos) partitioned drives and boot via MBR or first sector of drive. Windows 10 systems are normally UEFI and boot via an ESP - efi system partition on gpt partitioned drives. Can you run Boot-Repair report? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you messed up your **Master Boot Record** (MBR). Your query is not Ubuntu specific & therefore it is not a wise option to expect an apt response here still you can follow this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) or google for "How to repair / recover Windows 10 MBR"